# Extent from Centroids, Projection, and Resolution?

Tags: raster, r, extents, mercator

I have a file that defines a raster, although all the metadata was lost.  I know the lat/long coordinates of the grid centroids, and that the grid is in a Mercator projection with a 1/12deg equatorial resolution.  Is there any way to define the extent of the raster by just knowing the centroids and resolution?  Currently I'm doing:

```
xmin = min(longitude)-1/24
xmax = max(longitude)+1/24
ymin = min(latitude)-1/24
ymax = max(latitude)+1/24
```

Comment: What software and version are you using?

Comment: I'm using various packages within R.

Comment: What do you mean by the centroids? The center point of the corner cells? All cells?

Comment: @mkennedy Perhaps I should say the center point, and not centroid (???).  I have the center points for all cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extent of the raster is equal to the extent of the cell centres, expanded by half the resolution.

Here's an example:

1. Create a dummy raster with extent `c(0, 1, 0, 1)` and resolution `c(0.1, 0.1)`:

   ```
   library(raster)
   r <- raster(res=0.1, xmn=0, xmx=1, ymn=0, ymx=1)
   ```
2. Extract cell centres:

   ```
   p <- rasterToPoints(r)
   head(p)

   #         x    y
   # [1,] 0.05 0.95
   # [2,] 0.15 0.95
   # [3,] 0.25 0.95
   # [4,] 0.35 0.95
   # [5,] 0.45 0.95
   # [6,] 0.55 0.95
   ```
3. Calculate the extent of the cell centres:

   ```
   e <- extent(p)
   ```
4. Expand the extent by half the resolution. Note we don't need to specify `0.5 * res(r)`. The `+` method for `extent` objects yields a new extent that is `res(r)` units longer, overall, on each axis.

   ```
   e + res(r)

   # class       : Extent 
   # xmin        : 1.387779e-17 
   # xmax        : 1 
   # ymin        : -5.551115e-17 
   # ymax        : 1
   ```

(There's minor floating point error in the recovered extent.)

However, I don't see any problem with your approach, either:

```
min(p[, 'x']) - xres(r)/2
# [1] 0

max(p[, 'x']) + xres(r)/2
# [1] 1

min(p[, 'y']) - xres(r)/2
# [1] -6.938894e-17

max(p[, 'y']) + yres(r)/2
# [1] 1
```

Comment: Nice answer!  And thanks for confirming my initial thoughts!  I'm not a GIS analyst, and I just wanted to make sure I wasn't making an unreasonable assumption.